# how to make python aware of the cython module being installed in a location other than default

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I had to install the Cython compiler in a location other than default. It is a academic cluster and user programs must be installed in the user's home directories. So I installed Cython with:

```
python setup.py install --home=~
```

which went fine and installed the compiler in my home /bin directory which is in my $PATH.

To test it, I launch python and do:

```
> from Cython.Build import cythonize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Cython.Build
```

So how to make python aware of the Cython module being installed in a location other than default?

Comment: Have you tried to mess with the PYTHONPATH environment variable? See http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Comment: Aye PYTHONPATH! *curses* thanks for the tip, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that you use the `--home` parameter that way, have you tried to install via:

```
python setyp.py install --user
```

instead? This is the standard way to install python packages into your home directory. It will install everything in `/home/$YOU/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is appended to the `pythonpath` if it exist (usually it does not exist until you install something via the `--user` parameter).

Comment: Yep, that works too, that is if python knows to look there. I guess --home is usefull if you want a directory other than the default --user. (I hate ~/.local). Anyway I solved it by configuring PYTHONPATH. Tx!